# Iphone Objective-c global variable different value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, cocoa-touch

I have a C header file like this:

```
#ifndef RENDERER_H
#define RENDERER_H
static int g_count = 0;
static inline void g_addVertex(...) {
    ...
    g_count++;
}
static inline void g_flush() {
    ...
    g_count = 0;
}
#endif
```

I have an Objective-C class like this:

```
...
#include "Renderer.h"

@implementation Sprite
...
-(void)draw:(float)dt {
    ...
    g_addVertex(...); //6 times
}
```

In the iOS OpenGL template in ES1Renderer.m I create a Sprite instance. In the render methon in ES1Renderer I call the draw method of this instance, and the g_count variable counts normally in the draw method.(Its value 6 after six g_addVertex(...) function call in draw)

But after I call the g_flush() function in the render method of the ES1Renderer, right after the Sprite instance draw method called, in the g_flush() the value of the g_count variable is 0.
It should be for example 6 after six g_addVertex() in draw method of the Sprite class.

Help me please i don't know why the g_count change to 0, there is no other functions or something between them where i change its value.

Comment: You are aware that in the `g_flush` method you have `g_count = 0;` which sets g_count to 0.

Comment: The first line of g_flush is NSLog(@"count: %d", g_count); and its always prints 0. And in debug if i move the cursor to the g_count it shows 6, but when the program step into the g_flush() it shows 0. (befor the g_count = 0; executed)

Comment: If i move the cursor to the g_count variable in the NSLog(@"count: %d", g_count); it shows 0. But if i move the cursor to the g_count in the line static int g_count = 0; in Renderer.h it shows 6... If it is the same global variable, why not equal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A static variable is decidedly **not** global. A static variable has **file scope** and **internal linkage**, so each file that includes the header will get its own `g_count`. If you want a global variable, just write `int g_count` in one implementation file and put `extern int g_count` in a header that other files using that global variable will import.